# What are possible cases making window.history.state null on browser back?

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser-history, pushstate, html5-history

I have my website's query string URL like:

```
?budget=0-&year=0-&kms=0-&so=-1&sc=-1&pn=1
```

When user go to next page (From page 1 to page 2):

1. We explicity increment `pn` (page number by 1) and set it in query string URL.

   Changed query string:

   ```
   ?budget=0-&year=0-&kms=0-&so=-1&sc=-1&pn=2
   ```

   I also store the old query string, it looks like:

   ```
   ?budget=0-&year=0-&kms=0-&so=-1&sc=-1&pn=1
   ```
2. I then push both to window history to change URL and save previous for browser back:

   ```
   window.history.pushState(oldQS, null, newQS);
   ```
3. After doing this, when I am on page2, I check `window.history.state`. It stores my previous state:

   ```
   ?budget=0-&year=0-&kms=0-&so=-1&sc=-1&pn=1
   ```
4. I press browser back from page2 to get back to page1. I put a breakpoint on:

   ```
   $(window).on('popstate', function(e) {
       console.log(e.originalEvent.state)
   });
   ```

   `e.originalEvent.state` is `null`.

#### Observations:

- The `window.history.state` is not `null` and stores correct value when I am on page2.
- It gets `null` value when I click browser back.

#### What I have done so far:

*(Has not worked.)*

- put breakpoint on `hashchange` event but didn't help as there's no # in the URL.
- put breakpoint on every `window.history` function on my Javascript code like `pushState()`, `replaceState()` but none of it is getting hit when I press browser back.

I don't know what all other places/function to look at which might be changing `window.history.state` to `null`.

How can I figure out how and where did it become null by clicking browser back?

Comment: is `history.state` null as well, or does it have your info as expected?

Comment: history.state is null too.

Comment: oh, you don't have a state for page1, you only define the state for page2. then when you go back, page1 doesn't have any state because whatever got the user to page1 doesn't have a state tied to the page.

Comment: when user go to page2 from page1, i have stored page1 state:
window.history.pushState(oldQS, null, newQS);
oldQS has page1 state.

Comment: yes, but you're storing `oldQS` for page2, not for page1... you have to set such a state _before_ "going" to a page. how do you set the state _before_ going to page1? (i don't think you do...)

Comment: When user click on next button:
i save old query string (pn=1) in oldQS, create new QS (pn=2). Do window.history.pushState(oldQS, null, newQS);
and then hit api with newQS parameters.

Comment: well, you can always use `localStorage` or `sessionStorage` or `window.name` to store the queryString in a way page1 can reach...

Comment: i want it for multiple other scenarios..not just for page1 to page2, i have filters, sort parameter too and i want to store state one by one using html5 history api.

Answer (score 1):

You asked:

> I don't know what all other places/function to look at which might be changing window.history.state to null.
>
> How can I figure out how and where did it become null by clicking browser back?

Let's read the W3C HTML5 specification:

> [5.5.2 The History interface](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#the-history-interface)
>
> ...
>
> The state attribute of the History interface must return the last value it was set to by the user agent. Initially, its value must be null.

Conclusion: when the document loaded, the `history.state` is initially `null`.

> [5.6.10 History traversal](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#history-traversal)
>
> When a user agent is required to traverse the history to a specified entry, [...], the user agent must act as follows.
>
> ...
>
> 10. If the entry is a state object entry, let state be a structured clone of that state object. Otherwise, let state be null.
>
> ...
>
> 12. Let state changed be true if the Document of the specified entry has a latest entry, and that entry is not the specified entry; otherwise let it be false.
>
> ...
>
> 14. 1. If state changed is true, fire a trusted event with the name popstate at the Window object of the Document, using the PopStateEvent interface, with the state attribute initialized to the value of state. [...]

Conclusion: when navigating back to the state when the document was loaded, the state triggered with the `popstate` event is `null`.

Answer (score 0):

I spent a long time confused about this. What @dandavis said in the comments is the issue. The solution I used, which the comments don’t quite mention, is that I need to call replaceState immediately on page load before I start messing around with pushState. I pass the initial state - whatever it took to render the page at first - to replaceState.