# window.onpopstate event state null on second back button

Tags: javascript, html, dom, browser-history, html5-history

I am using this to change the URL and push to the history stack:

`history.pushState({ }, null, url);`

It works. Then, I implement reload on pop:

```
window.onpopstate = function (e) {
    if (e && e.state) {
        location.reload();
    }
}
```

It works on the first back button and reloads the page. However, when it reloads the page, push state history seems to be gone. When I try to go back again, it fails as `e.state` is null. There appears to be a similar problem at [window.history.state becoming null, what all could be possible cases making it null or changing its state on browser back?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35924802/window-history-state-becoming-null-what-all-could-be-possible-cases-making-it-n) (though I'm not sure if it's the same thing) without a solution.

One may ask "why not just reload on every pop, without the if statement?". This is not possible as `onpopstate` is also called on my AJAX calls, popups etc at many places on the page, also with `e.state` being null, and I shouldn't reload on such scenarios. That's when I'm pushing an extra empty object on push.

As another approach, I've tried passing the whole document (`document.documentElement.innerHTML`) into the state as a variable and then checking for that variable and restoring from it if it exists, but it messes up my whole DOM too, so I've abandoned it.

How can I make back and forward buttons work, without breaking anything that also calls `onpopstate`?